# I want to schedule an Oracle Sql script to run on the database server

Tags: oracle, cron, sqlplus, cron-task

I want to schedule an Oracle Sql script to run using Sql*Plus on my database server at midnight.

Currently I run it manually using:

```
nohup sqlplus username/password @myscript.sql &
```

How can I schedule it? I don't want to pass username and password openly. Is there a way to hide it?

Comment: Are you using MS SQL server? You always can use SQL Agent for this purpose. username/password could be encripted by system (If you will use one of system users or event domain user).

Comment: If you are using SQL Server version with no SQL Agent available the other possibility is to create a windows task and run a batch file pointing to a procedure on the SQL Server

Comment: It is server of my company running on linux.

Answer (score 0):

One way of 'hiding' your password:

In the script do a

```
CONN username/password
```

Then run your script as:

```
sqlplus /nolog @script_name
```